# Removing audio data from an aws-s3 bucket

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, permissions, promise

I use javascript in a cloud function, using promises to remove audio data from an aws-s3 server.
Here is the relevant code:

```
 var audioRmvPromises = [];
 const s3 = new aws.S3();
 for (i = 0; i < resSentence.length; i++) {
   // Let us remove the audio data:
   audioRmvPromises.push(s3.deleteObject({
     Bucket: "londonspeak",
     Key: resSentence[i].get("audio")
   }).promise());
 }

 return Parse.Promise.when(audioRmvPromises);
```

Since I have similar code working in other places. I suspect that rather than the code, I probably have wrong permissions set. How can I check that all the permissions are OK (on my s3-bucket)?

Comment: Did you take look at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/set-permissions.html)?

Comment: You haven't given us any information about the error you are getting.

Comment: There is no error that I can see. It is just that the audio files are not deleted as they should be.

Comment: @Venkatesh Yes I have read the document you mention, at least part of it. I have already fiddle with policies, but I don't exactly see how to make the link between those and my cloud function. I suppose this is what I am missing.